# How to locate the XPATH of the Continue button on LinkedIn?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, linkedin-api

I right clicked the button, selected "Inspect" command and copied and used both XPATH and full XPATH. Neither of them worked for any of the commands below.

- xpath = '//*[@id="ember949"]/footer/button[1]'
- xpath_full = '/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/artdeco-tabs/artdeco-tabpanel[2]/form/footer/button[1]'
- button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
- button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath_full)))

Can someone please explain? Thank you.

Comment: Please post the relevant part of the HTML, I saw no such button. Without the HTML the question will not benefit future users.

Comment: The HTML file is too large to paste it here. The link to the webpage is linkedin.com/job-apply/2821134430 and right click and Inspect.

Answer (score 0):

Without the HTML, I cannot give a definitive answer.
Looks like the first id may be dynamic and could change.
As for the second one, the full XPaths are brittle and I do not use them at all.
There could be an iframe that you should switch to first.

Comment: The HTML file is too large to paste it here. The link to the webpage is https://www.linkedin.com/job-apply/2821134430 and right click and Inspect.

Answer (score 0):

You could try searching the entire page for a button element with the `continue-btn` class:

```
//button[@class='continue-btn']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the Selector / CSS Selector. In the code just change

```
By.XPATH
```

to:

```
By.CSS_SELECTOR
```

and instead of copying the XPATH copy the Selector or in some cases CSS Selector.